# Disable signature enforcement

Tags: windows, kernel, driver

I know that this problem has been stated multiple times, but I cannot seem to find any solution. The issue is that I compiled in release mode the [kmdf hello world example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/gettingstarted/writing-a-very-small-kmdf--driver) from Microsoft's website, but I am not able to run it. The reason is that when I try to launch the service, I get the following error: "The driver has been blocked from loading". I Obviously get this error because I have not signed the driver, but even though I have disabled signature enforcement on my updated Windows 10 machine (as stated [here](https://windowsreport.com/driver-blocked-from-loading-fix/)) I still cannot launch the driver, and I get exact the same message. So basically the option for temporarily deactivating signature enforcement, seems to serve a completely decorative purpose. So, is there any other way to launch my unsigned driver on my Windows 10 Virtual Machine, or I need to pay $100 to run my code on my own computer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorial that you're using mentions that you need to provision your target machine for driver deployment, and leads to the "[Provision a computer for driver deployment and testing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/gettingstarted/provision-a-target-computer-wdk-8-1)" page which (among other things) has the following instructions:

> On the target computer, run the WDK Test Target Setup MSI that matches
>   the platform of the target computer. You can find the MSI in the
>   Windows Driver Kit (WDK) installation directory under Remote.
>
> Example: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Remote\x64\WDK Test
>   Target Setup x64-x64_en-us.msi

If you want to deploy your driver manually (for example, if you're testing your driver on your development machine or in a VM), instead of running the aforementioned MSI you can manually enable test signing mode by running `bcdedit -set TESTSIGNING ON` from the elevated command prompt. You would need to reboot the machine for the changes to take effect.

See "[The TESTSIGNING Boot Configuration Option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/the-testsigning-boot-configuration-option)" on MSDN for additional details.